# Window function query that is cognizant of previous occurrences of the partition value

Tags: postgresql

I have daily data for a user that looks like this:

```
the_date   | status
2015-12-01 | active
2015-12-02 | active
2015-12-03 | inactive
2015-12-04 | inactive
2015-12-05 | inactive
2015-12-06 | active
2015-12-07 | active
```

I would like to add a new column `days_in_current_status` that sums the # of days this user has been in her current status, but treat the two separate chains of 'active' as two different statuses, such that the result looks like this:

```
the_date   | status   | days_in_current_status
2015-12-01 | active   | 1
2015-12-02 | active   | 2
2015-12-03 | inactive | 1
2015-12-04 | inactive | 2
2015-12-05 | inactive | 3
2015-12-06 | active   | 1
2015-12-07 | active   | 2
```

How could I do this?

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY the_date)` is insufficient for me since it'd label the 2015-12-06 row as 4 and the below it as 5. It'd work if I can add a column that restates the last 2 `status` values as 'active2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. First, add yesterday's status to the table to be able to compare with today's status:

```
SELECT
*, LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY the_date) AS status_yesterday
FROM table

the_date   | status  | status_yesterday
2015-12-01 | active  | NULL
2015-12-02 | active  | active
2015-12-03 | inactive| active
2015-12-04 | inactive| inactive
2015-12-05 | inactive| inactive
2015-12-06 | active  | inactive
2015-12-07 | active  | active
```

Then compute cases when they're not the same:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN status = status_yesterday THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS transition
FROM table

the_date   | status  | status_yesterday| transition
2015-12-01 | active  | NULL            | 1
2015-12-02 | active  | active          | 0
2015-12-03 | inactive| active          | 1
2015-12-04 | inactive| inactive        | 0
2015-12-05 | inactive| inactive        | 0
2015-12-06 | active  | inactive        | 1
2015-12-07 | active  | active          | 0
```

Then sum over the transitions to construct a status_id:

```
SELECT *, SUM(transition) OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY the_date)
FROM table

the_date   | status  | status_yesterday| transition | status_id
2015-12-01 | active  | NULL            | 1          | 1
2015-12-02 | active  | active          | 0          | 1
2015-12-03 | inactive| active          | 1          | 1
2015-12-04 | inactive| inactive        | 0          | 1
2015-12-05 | inactive| inactive        | 0          | 1
2015-12-06 | active  | inactive        | 1          | 2
2015-12-07 | active  | active          | 0          | 2
```

Now the concatenation of `status` and `status_id` can be used to identify distinct chains to partition by.

Taken together:

```
WITH add_yesterday_status AS (
    SELECT the_date
    , status
    , LAG(status) OVER (
        PARTITION BY 1
        ORDER BY the_date
      ) AS status_yesterday
    FROM table
)

, add_transition AS (
    SELECT *
    , CASE WHEN status = status_yesterday THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS transition
    FROM add_yesterday_status
)

, add_status_id AS (
    SELECT *
    , SUM(transition) OVER (
        PARTITION BY status
        ORDER BY the_date
      ) AS status_id
    FROM add_transition
)

, add_days_in_current_status AS (
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY status, status_id
        ORDER BY the_date
      ) AS days_in_current_status
)

SELECT the_date
, status
, days_in_current_status
FROM add_days_in_current_status
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed have daily values then you can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE stat (the_date, status, days_in_current_status) AS (
  SELECT min(the_date), status, 1
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY status
  UNION
  SELECT t.the_date, t.status,
         CASE WHEN t.status = s.status THEN s.days_in_current_status + 1 ELSE 1 END
  FROM mytable t
  JOIN stat s ON s.the_date + 1 = t.the_date
)
SELECT * FROM stat
ORDER BY the_date;
```

Result:

```
psql (9.5.0)
Type "help" for help.

test=# WITH RECURSIVE stat (the_date, status, days_in_current_status) AS (
test(#   SELECT min(the_date), status, 1
test(#   FROM mytable
test(#   GROUP BY status
test(#   UNION
test(#   SELECT t.the_date, t.status,
test(#          CASE WHEN t.status = s.status THEN s.days_in_current_status + 1 ELSE 1 END
test(#   FROM mytable t
test(#   JOIN stat s ON s.the_date + 1 = t.the_date
test(# )
test-# SELECT * FROM stat
test-# ORDER BY the_date;
  the_date  |  status  | days_in_current_status
------------+----------+------------------------
 2015-12-01 | active   |                      1
 2015-12-02 | active   |                      2
 2015-12-03 | inactive |                      1
 2015-12-04 | inactive |                      2
 2015-12-05 | inactive |                      3
 2015-12-06 | active   |                      1
 2015-12-07 | active   |                      2
(7 rows)
```

If you have gaps in your dates you could do a `generate_series()` on the date range of interest